# in R, trying to omit the empty set in indexing

Tags: r, indexing

a function gives me a vector of strings and I want to remove those entries that do not "look good".

```
> area
[1] "US_GAF_15"  "den helder"
```

the one not "looking good" is the second one, it's a geographic name and not a code of a location. I describe geographic names as names that contain lower case letters.

```
>   area <- area[-grep("[a-z]", area)]
```

this does not work if there is no geographic name in the set.

```
> -grep("[a-z]", area)
integer(0)
> area[-grep("[a-z]", area)]
character(0)
```

I know I can do this by putting the selection behind a simple `if`, but do you see an other way to do it.  I hope to be surprised by some unexpected programming style.

Comment: what's the intended output would be when there is a NULL set? You may also want to look at the related function `grepl()` when returns a set of booleans corresponds to each item in your vector. And finally, can you provide an example where there is "no geographic name in the set"?

Comment: I see the answers showing how to use grepl and I did not know that function. there is no "bad looking" object after I've filtered them out. I want the operation to be idempotent. if the input set is empty, I definitely want an empty result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` instead of `grep`, since it returns a logical vector.

```
area <- area[!grepl("[a-z]", area)]
```

---

Edit: This is idempotent, as you descibe it.  Compare:

```
cleanArea <- function(x, pattern="[a-z]"){
  x[!grepl(pattern, x)]
}

> cleanArea(c("US_GAF_15", "den helder"))
[1] "US_GAF_15"

> cleanArea(c("US_GAF_15"))
[1] "US_GAF_15"

> cleanArea(c("den Helder"))
character(0)

> cleanArea(NULL)
NULL

> cleanArea(character(0))
character(0)
```

Comment: is indexing (`[`) faster than using `subset`?

Comment: Very probably.  But more importantly, the help for `?subset` states to only ever use `subset` for interactive use. Because of that health warning, I never, ever use `subset`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grepl` with `subset`:

```
subset(area, !grepl("[a-z]", area) )
```

Less compact and less readable would be:

```
area[ ! area %in% grep("[a-z]", area, value=TRUE) )
```

Comment: grepl seems to be the key, but how are you using it? your code does not work here (Error in grepl("[a-z]") : argument "x" is missing, with no default)

Comment: ooops, will add the area argument that was missing.

Comment: (you also want to correct the other expression)...  but why would one prefer `subset`?

Comment: Actually I had it in there but also an extra ")" that was causing an error further illustrating the perils of untested code. `subset` generalizes nicely to full datasets where it allows you to specify not just which rows you want using the 'subset' argument, but also which columns. It creates an environment where the columns names do not need quoting.